# Can't create new project after update to android studio 3.4. Arch based Antergos Linux

Tags: arch-linux, android-studio

Getting following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a JavaToKotlinConversionProvider, even though one should be bundled with Studio
```

Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998585/i-cant-create-a-new-project) over on stack overflow.

I recently updated to android studio 3.4, I followed the advice on that other thread and on the Kotlin plugin section it states "Incompatible with the current Android Studio version", even though the version number explicitly references Studio 3.4 (See attached image).

Image of Kotlin Plugin information from my Android Studio:

[image: kotlin-plugin-info]

As stated in Question title using Antergos, arch-based linux. "uname -r" command gives response of: 5.0.7-arch1-1-ARCH

I have tried enabling and disabling, can't make any progress, don't see an option to uninstall or reinstall.

It's especially maddening as I need android studio to revise for an exam.

Please help if you can.

More important edit: just to say Android studio opens and runs, it opens existing projects and can run and build them, but creating new ones just won't work with the above error issuing.

Edit: Just to say, I initially intended to ask over on stack overflow, but it guided me to ask here.

Comment: One of my issues was that I was referring to a symlinked directory. Oddly, that's fine for Java projects, but not Kotlin. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove the AUR installed version of android-studio `sudo pacman -R android-studio` and then download the version from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/) and followed their [install instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install).

Can create projects again now.

Comment: Funnily enough, an earlier version of kotlin plugin is present using this method.